# Docker toolbox and xdebug

Tags: docker, xdebug

I am using a docker toolbox on my computer on Windows 10 Family. I ran my IDE with xdebug on my host machine. Docker engine is on a VM machine, which hosts my containers

ip of host machine : 192.168.1.50
ip of docker machine : 192.168.99.100

sample of my docker-compose.yml :

```
    php:
        build: '.'
        volumes: 
        - ./code:/var/www/html/xxx
        - ./docker/apache/vhosts:/etc/apache2/sites-enabled
        - $PWD/docker/php/conf.d:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d
        ports:
        - 8097:80
```

I can reach with my webbrowser, the website into my container, with address : 192.168.99.100:8097

I would like debug with xdebug.

config of xdebug :

```
zend_extension=/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20190902/xdebug.so
xdebug.remote_enable = 1
xdebug.remote_autostart = 1
xdebug.remote_connect_back = 0
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.remote_host = host.docker.internal
xdebug.remote_idekey ="PHPSTORM"
xdebug.remote_log = /var/log/xdebug_remote.log
```

The problem :
xdebug contacts my VM machine on port 9000.
I must configure to make bind between my VM machine and my host machine.

Which configurations should I use?
Should I use port forwarding?

Thanks in advance for your help/suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

You write:

> ip of host machine : 192.168.1.50 ip of docker machine : 192.168.99.100

That means that they are not on the same network, which sounds strange. It is likely that your host machine also has a 192.168.99.x address (check with `sudo ifconfig`).

Xdebug lives inside your docker container with PHP, and needs to make a connection **to** your IDE, which should live on the IP address that `host.docker.internal` refers too. Your INI settings show that you're making an Xdebug log file (`/var/log/xdebug_remote.log`) so check what connection Xdebug is trying to make to talk to your IDE (and include that in your question).

Comment: In fact, docker toolbox, at the first run of docker quickstart terminal, created a VM with this IP.

Comment: In fact, docker toolbox, at the first run of docker quickstart terminal, created a VM with this IP.
In virtualbox, settings "network" : 
card 1: NAT 
card 2 : host private network

Do i switch first card, to "bridge access" ?

it's OK with this rule : xdebug into my container needs to make a connection to my IDE

host.docker.internal refers to my VM machine, for the moment.